# The glyphicon disappears when I click on another button

Tags: html, css, glyphicons

I'm using glyphicon's in my html page. When I load the page the glyphicon appears perfect. But when I click a different link the glyphicon disappears into a box.

```
<button style="height:30px;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span *ngIf="x.filename" style="color:#15566D;" (click)="pdf_toggle(x)"> 
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>
                </span></button>
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: <button style="height:30px;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span *ngIf="x.filename" style="color:#15566D;" (click)="pdf_toggle(x)"> 
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>
                </span>

Comment: Please include it in the content of your post, ideally as a "code snippet" so anyone can run your code in their browser.

Comment: what does (click)="pdf_toggle(x)" do? I suspect this is making x = undefined

Comment: If you are using Chrome, hit F12 to see if there are fonts, css or scripts that are not loading or if there is errors in JavaScript that are causing that undesired effect.

Comment: The pdf_toggle(x) displays the file intended, clicking on the glyphicon doesn't affect it, but when I click on a different button on the page the glyphicon changes into a box.